# Can't backup iphone to icloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

My iphone hasn't backed up to icloud in over 19 weeks. I have deleted hundreds of pictures, turned off Mail, Reminders, Safari, Notes, and Passbook and still it says there is no room.  The only thing that is on to backup is calendar and contacts.  Can this be right?

Comment: Do you have any apps taking up a lot of space or other devices?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the iCloud tab on your iPhone, you can see the details there and remove stuff you don't want anymore.

1. Settings
2. iCloud
3. Just above **Delete account** click **storage and backup** (this is probably named different)
4. Click **manage storage**
5. You can manage your data here and check what's taking up the space.

Comment: I have 260MB of 5GB used, and I can still not do the backup. I set almost nothing to be backed up.