# Cannot make iCloud backup with iPhone 5

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, iphone

My iPhone 5 cannot make any backups anymore. My last backup is from June 2015. I have checked if:

- I have enough space in iCloud (about 3 GB).
- The size of the backup (approximately 790 MB).
- Removed many photos from my iPhone.

Followed these steps:

- Turn off iCloud drive, reboot, and turn on safety backup again (no success).
- Turn off iCloud, reboot, and turn on iCloud again (no success).
- Sign out of iCloud. turn off phone, turn on again and login to iCloud again (no success).
- Removed my latest backup in iCloud (which turned of safety backup) and turned on safety backup. Again with no success.

And what makes it even worse is that the iPhone reports no error message telling me why my backup failed.

How can I make this work again?

Links I already read and used:

[iPhone 5 backup to iCloud not starting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192915/iphone-5-backup-to-icloud-not-starting)

[Can't backup iphone to icloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135558/cant-backup-iphone-to-icloud)

In Dutch: [Kan geen reservekopie meer maken in iCloud met iPhone 5](http://forum.iculture.nl/f147/icloud/f148/icloud/126819-geen-reservekopie-meer-maken-icloud-iphone-5-a.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to start backup manually. Did you tried that? If so what it tells you.

Also, as far as i know you need to have a wifi connection for backup to work.

PS: i wanted to post this as a comment but dont have enough rep yet. So if someone put that on comment i can delete answer, since its really not an answer

Comment: Yes, i tried to manually make an icloud backup. That is what fails every time. The auto backup should not even start as most of the time my iPhone is not connected to Wi-Fi and electricity.